# How to bulk Edit Dates in Media Library?

Tags: media, media-library, bulk

I can't seem to find this option, but is there a way to bulk edit the dates of media items? I'm trying to go through my media and clean it up and I'd like to batch edit the dates of images (they'd be the same date for each batch), but can't seem to find a reference at all to this issue.

Comment: what is the syntax
of the date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a plugin called [Media Library Assistant](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-assistant/).

1. After you install it go to your **Media > Assitant** (`wp-admin/upload.php?page=mla-menu`).
2. Select all the images or the ones you want to edit.
3. Click on **Bulk Actions**.
4. Click on **Edit** and then **Apply**.
5. Then you will see **Uploaded on** and use the date you wish.

[image]